# A FUSE like file system

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, fuse

I need to develop my own file-system. The thing is that I only need a specific behavior in a few callbacks (such as read, write, open etc.) and I don't want to wast time on dealing with Inodes and creating a new FS from scratch.

I have once stumbled upon FUSE (file-system in user space), and that is almost every thing I need, except FUSE has over head (copy to and from user) because it is in user space.

Is there something like FUSE, but in kernel space? or is there a way to avoid the copy_to and copy_from?

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you look at the kernel-space implementation of FUSE for pointers?

Comment: Are you SURE that doing it in userspace will definitely be a performance problem? Because kernel code is awfully tricky and hard to maintain.

Comment: looking inside FUSE for pointers would be more time consuming than learning the whole thing by my self, and my top priority is to save time.

Comment: yes, I'm sure that userspace needs copy_from and copy_to user - two copies instead of one as the usual FS needs.

Comment: I didn't ask whether you were sure it called copy_from_user, I asked whether you were sure it was a PROBLEM. We know FUSE copies the data from userspace (in fact, often twice depending on the implementation of the FUSE fs), but is it REALLY a PROBLEM for YOU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save time, implement in FUSE and when your functionality is complete and stable, look to port it into the kernel.

It is likely that the copy performance will not be an impediment, so the kernel port can be avoided.

- Rick "Premature optimization is a root evil"